# Send a message from slack user to another slack user with apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, slack

how to configure a spring boot project to Send a message from slack user to another slack user with apache camel ?

here is the code need to be configured:

```
public class SlackRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        String WEB_HOOK_ROUTE = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXX/YYYYYYYYYY/ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";

        from("direct:testSlack")).to("slack:@slack-user?webhookUrl="+WEB_HOOK_ROUTE);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `username` property for configuring your producer.

For example:

```
public class SlackRouter extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    String WEB_HOOK_ROUTE = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXX/YYYYYYYYYY/ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";

    from("direct:testSlack")).to("slack:@slack-user?username=MYUSERNAME&webhookUrl="+WEB_HOOK_ROUTE);

}
```

}